# What does Robert C. Martin mean by SQL being unnecessary?

Tags: architecture, enterprise-architecture, architectural-patterns, plugin-architecture

I've been reading/watching a lot of Robert C. Martin content. I've come across him saying SQL is unnecessary because of solid state drives. When I search other sources to back this up I get a bunch of random articles describing the difference of SQL performance between hard drives and solid state drives (which is related but not what I'm trying to research).

Ultimately, I do not understand what he's trying to get at. Is he saying replace SQL with No-SQL technologies? Is he saying store data in files in a file system? Or does he just want people to stop using SQL/Relational Databases because of SQLi attacks? I fear I'm missing the point he's trying to make.

I will provide some links here so you can read straight from his mind:

1. [Bobby Tables](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/12/03/BobbyTables.html)
2. [Clean Architecture Lecture](https://youtu.be/Nsjsiz2A9mg?t=42m20s)

First, he states that SQL should be removed from the system entirely.

> The solution. The only solution. Is to eliminate SQL from the system
>   entirely. If there is no SQL engine, then there can be no SQLi
>   attacks.

And although he talks about replacing SQL with an API, I do NOT think he means putting SQL behind an API because of that previous quote and what he says earlier in the article.

> Frameworks don’t handle the issue;...

*Side note: In saying SQL, I'm pretty sure Robert means most relational databases. Maybe not all but most. In any case, most people are using SQL anyways. so...*

If SQL is not being used to persists data, then what are we supposed to use?

Before answering that, I should also note. Robert emphasizes that solid state drives should change the tools that we use to persist data. [Søren D. Ptæus's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366590/261944) answer points this out.

I must also respond to the, "but data integrity" group. Upon some further research, Robert says we should use transactional databases like [datomic](http://augustl.com/blog/2016/datomic_the_most_innovative_db_youve_never_heard_of/). Then CRUD turns into CR (create and read) and SQL transactions go away altogether. Data integrity is of course important.

I can't find a question that encompasses all of this. I guess I'm looking for alternatives that match Robert's guidelines. Datomic is one but is that it? What other options match these guidelines? And do they actually work better with solid state drives?

Comment: Have you read the last paragraph of the first link ("Bobby Tables")?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand because I don't know what the difference is between doing that and what I've been doing my whole career. Is it like making REST calls to a SQL service is okay as long as it is separate from your microservice? Or, is the repository pattern good enough?

Comment: What does he mean by replace SQL with an API? Aren’t those totally different things?

Comment: Does this https://xkcd.com/327/ help explain why SQL is considered harmful?  The way I read it, he considers SQL to be a major security/attack surface which doesn't make it "unnecessary" but does make it something that should be carefully abstracted from the user interface.

Comment: @christo8989 - "What does he mean by replace SQL with an API?". I interpret him to mean that you don't have textual query language (that gets passed to a SQL engine) all over your codebase. You hide this behind an API which exposes only safe mechanisms to describe queries. Internal to the API something has to generate commands to the SQL engine, but that is a smaller surface area in which you can enforce use of parameter binding, etc, control who makes changes, etc.

Comment: @andrew: That's not what Bob says.  He doesn't say to hide the SQL behind an API; he says to avoid SQL altogether.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So what does it mean to replace it with an api?

Comment: Do you know what an API is?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No.

Comment: **A**pplication **P**rogramming **I**nterface.  REST is an example.  So is the public-facing surface of a class.  Method signatures and their return values and types form part of an API.  See https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/api/what-is-an-api

Comment: But, but, but... SQL *is* an API. It is the API for an RDBMS. It just happens to be a very powerful API that can be easily misused.

Comment: If you create a DB API that doesn't have a textual interface, sooner or later some poor programmer would write code that looks like this: `eval(request.GET["table_name"] + ".get(pk=" + request.GET["pk"] + ")"))`. It's not SQL that's really at fault, but poor, ignorant programmers.

Comment: @LieRyan: sure, but most programmers won't probably use this kind of dynamic query creation without a real need, when there is a safe and easy to use API available. That is because a safe API should make it less effort to create safe queries, and more effort to create unsafe ones. SQL as an API does it the other way round: it makes it less effort to create unsafe queries, and that is the issue with it.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I'm pretty sure that SQL is a language.  It's what the 'L' stands for in the 'SQL'.  ODBC or JDBC are examples of APIs.

Comment: @JimmyJames SQL is a language yes, but that doesn't mean it's not an API. SQL is a language that provides an API for accessing some underlying storage.

Comment: @Cubic I'm not sure if or where we can find an authoritative definition but I disagree.  SQL does much more than access data.  Are you suggesting that all languages are APIs?  I really don't think it's useful to muddle terms this way.

Comment: SQL was designed so that someone could type it in to a command line and get results. Why it was ever moved in to source code is a story of a slow-motion disaster which is yet to be explained. No one ever made DOS in to an Embedded language, or the Korn Shell. Stupid.

Comment: @nocomprende SQL was always designed to be used for applications. It would have been virtually useless otherwise. The point always was to give applications some way to store and retrieve data without messing with weird custom formats or even having to care a whole lot about how the data is stored.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to access a relational database without using SQL. The two are separate ideas. I have seen it done, and that is what should have been done.

Comment: Ugh ... I like Uncle Bob. But, the dude likes expressing *way* stronger opinions than even *he* really believes -- [e.g., his very-vocal "TDD-everything" opinion](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/04/30/When-tdd-does-not-work.html). I'd read most of what Uncle Bob writes as an exaggeration aimed at somewhat overcorrecting the sins of young software dev's ...

Comment: @svidgen: Unlike the article that is the subject of this post (or Bob's declaration during a HanselMinutes interview wherein he declares that "If you're not using Test-Driven Development, you can't call yourself a professional"), I found the article you linked quite reasonable.

Comment: Why does not a single one of these answers, or even comments, address the primary point of the question, which has to do with whether there's a relationship between the desirability of SQL and the use of solid state drives?

Comment: Martin is known for his provocative nonsense, particularly among DBAs and DB developers.  In fact, this question has already been answered at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158957/do-ssds-reduce-the-usefulness-of-databases/158958 where they hang out.

Comment: @Beanluc because the answerers are not DB experts (to be fair, Robert Harvey's answer is dead on). See the above-linked answer by those who are.  But to be clear: SSDs have nothing to do with SQL's advantages or disadvantages relative to non-SQL options.  Martin simply does not know what he is talking about (or doesn't care).

Comment: @Beanluc I didn't because SSDs aren't mentioned in the "Bobby Tables" link (so I don't know what, if anything, Robert C. Martin said about SSDs).

Comment: Here's another Uncle Bob's blog post where he talks about relational databases and SSDs: http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/12/09/Dbtails.html . But unfortunately it doesn't really illuminate the topic much further for me.

Comment: Ironically, this question was much more focused and valid (IE., not opinion-oriented) *before* the many edits and "clarifications" turned into a rambling subjective monologue.

Comment: @JimmyJames _Are you suggesting that all languages are APIs?_ Why? "SQL is a language but that doesn't mean it's not an API" does not mean "If something is a language then it's also an API", it means "If something is a language it might still be also an API".

Comment: @SantiBailors It was a question not a statement.

Answer (score 75):

Bob Martin is clearly exaggerating to make his point more clear. But what is his point?

> Does he just want people to stop using SQL/Relational Databases because of SQLi attacks?

To my understanding, in that blog post (your first link) Martin tries to convince people to stop using SQL, but not relational databases. These are **two different things**.

SQL is an extremely powerful language, and it is standardized to some degree. It allows to create complex queries and commands in a very compact manner, in a readable, understandable, easy to learn fashion. It does not depend on another programming language, so it is usable for most application programmers, no matter if they prefer Java, C, C++, C#, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, Basic, Go, Perl, PHP, or something else.

However, **this power comes for a cost**: writing safe SQL queries/commands is harder than writing unsafe ones. A safe API should make it easy to create safe queries "by default". Potentially unsafe ones should need more mental or at least more typing effort. That is IMHO why Martin is ranting against SQL in its current form.

The problem is not new, and there are safer APIs than standard SQL to access a relational database. For example, all OR mappers I know are trying to provide such an API (though they are typically designed for other primary goals). Static SQL variants make it hard to create any dynamic queries with unsanitized input data (and that is not a new invention: Embedded SQL, which uses often static SQL, is around 30 years old).

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any API which is as flexible, as standardized, mature, language-independent and also as powerful as SQL, especially dynamic SQL. That's why I have some doubts about Martin's suggestion of "not using SQL" as a realistic way of solving the mentioned problems. So read his article as a thought into the right direction, not as a "best practice" you can blindly follow from tomorrow on.

Comment: At least we can avoid using it for any writing operation usually with what ORM-like stuff provide. As for querying the database, you can already do quite some stuff without writing your own SQL. Nowadays only "advanced" usage of the database capabitilies should require to write SQL or the use of complex datatype  (graph, geographic datas, recursive).

Comment: Martin does specifically argue that the API to use should *not* be as powerful as SQL; His argument that the power of SQL is the problem, not a feature. The API he's arguing for should be application specific, and only be as flexible and powerful as the application absolutely needs, not more. He's specifically arguing against inventing another string based query language.

Comment: @Walfrat: yes, that is the typical kind of safer API I had in mind. However, using ORMs is always a tradeoff, they are definitely not a silver bullet.

Comment: @Cubic: any solution to the problems mentioned by Martin probably need to be less powerful or less easy to use than SQL - that's their blessing and their curse.

Comment: @DocBrown One of Robert's thoughts is to stop using relational databases. I've heard him equate SQL to all relational databases. His suggestion is to use transactional databases (the first I've heard of this, kinda) instead of static data. So, I think he is also against relational databases in general and probably for multiple reasons. One other reason being the changing from HDs to SSDs.

Comment: @Cubic Isn't this just a variant of the age-old debate between high-level and low-level languages? HLLs are safer and more productive, LLLs are more powerful. Hacks like `asm` in C let you have your cake and eat it. Some ORMs have similar escapes to raw SQL.

Comment: @Barmar: SQL is about as high-level as you can get, and Bob is asserting that it is patently unsafe.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Everything is relative. It's high-level compared to writing all the file accessing directly, but it's low-level compared to an ORM library (although some of these are just direct mappings of SQL clauses to function calls, so maybe they're about the same level).

Comment: @christo8989: I don't think it will make much sense trying to write one answer as a respond to all of what Martin has once written or said in his career. My answer was one to the question give in your title, explaining mostly how the blog post in the first link you gave should IMHO be interpreted.

Comment: This answer has little-to-nothing to do with the question about SSDs and SQL.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: yes, I focussed on the core aspect of the question. The question in its current form is IMHO way-too-broad, especially after the OP tried to "improve" it by adding more and more additional question details about what Martin might have said and meant.

Answer (score 57):

Bob Martin's opinion is just that; one man's opinion.

A programmer is expected to understand the system he is writing well enough to exercise reasonable care about its security and performance.  That means that, if you're talking to a SQL database, you do what the [Bobby Tables](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom) [website](http://bobby-tables.com/) says to do: ***you sanitize your input data.***  It means that you put your SQL database on a machine that promises adequate performance. There are very well-known and well-understood ways to do these things, and while they don't guarantee absolute security or ideal performance, neither does anything else.

The assertion that we don't need SQL anymore because we now have SSD's is just specious.  SQL wasn't invented because high-speed hard drives didn't exist yet; it was invented because we needed an industry-standard way to express data-retrieval concepts. Relational database systems have many other qualities besides speed and security that make them ideal for business operations; in particular, [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).  Data integrity is at least as important as speed or security, and if you don't have it, then what's the point of securing bad data or retrieving it as quickly as possible?

Before you take one man's hysteria as gospel, I suggest you learn about application and system security and performance on their own terms, not by reading random Internet articles.  There's much more to security, performance and robust system design than simply "avoid this technology."

We don't ban kitchen knives because a few hapless individuals manage to accidentally cut their fingers with them.

Comment: I don't interpret Martin's articles as advocating abandoning RDBMSs, but rather to use alternative ways of interacting with them, e.g. LINQ-to-SQL or the JPA Criteria API, rather than directly encoding or manipulating SQL strings in our source code.

Comment: So we shouldn't blindly follow what he says ... but *what is he saying*?

Comment: One thing I really dislike about the community here is, as soon as you ask a question about doing something *the Clean Code/Uncle Bob -way*, is people swooping in telling you how you should do *something different*. "How to paint like van Gogh?" - "van Gogh was wrong, you should paint like Picasso instead".

Comment: @Jules Which is decent advise if whatever library/DSL supports the kind of queries you want to make (then again I suppose if you're doing some terribly complicated query that's probably something a DBA should be doing on the DB end anyway).

Comment: *sanitizing* input data to avoid injection attacks should be the backup option ***after using parametrized methods*** to separate code from input.

Comment: @Cubic - right: I'm not usually a supporter of stored procedures in general because I tend to think they make code evolution harder, but for any query that is so complex that it can't be performed using the APIs I mention, a stored procedure, maintained as part of the database rather than part of the application code, is likely the best approach.

Comment: @Jules, in the middle of the article, he explicitly says words to the effect if "your ORM/framework of choice will not save you!" So no, I don't believe he's advocating their use, either.  I agree with others, he states the problem and says to stop using SQL, but "use an API instead" is too generic to be useful advice, imo. Somewhere in the bowels of your system you're using *some* kind of persistence and that persistence layer has to be sanitized whether SQL or something else.

Comment: @TRiG If you are interested in **what he is actually saying** I made [an answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366590/197693) solely to cover this aspect of the question. Basically: "**Relational Databases are doomed**" and "**SQL is inherently flawed**".

Comment: *All* technology is doomed and essentially flawed. It is only a matter of time. Meanwhile, we have stuff that we need to do, with our flawed and doomed technologies.

Comment: @Paul - for one thing, Martin has a style that is *very* prone to hyperbole, and I think he was using that at the time.  He *cannot* really mean that if you use a proven, well-written ORM that does not use a text-based interface you could still be susceptible to SQL injection.  He mentions Hibernate as not being a solution -- which in itself it isn't, as HQL can be misused in just the same was as SQL is -- and that JPF isn't a solution -- I didn't know what that was, so googled it, and it seems to be a static analysis tool that can presumably detect SQL injection -- and that Rails can't ...

Comment: ... which is true, as the Rails query API allows raw SQL strings (see [documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and scan for a red warning box about the possibility of injection attacks).  And this is true, because all of these APIs can be used in a way that is just as bad as using raw SQL.  You do need either discipline to use them the right way or some kind of enforcement to ensure that they aren't used in inappropriate ways.  You need a method to isolate all SQL strings from being strings manipulated within your code, such that you can prove no SQL ...

Comment: ... crosses the interface.  With raw SQL APIs, it can be very hard to perform such a proof.  With something that uses structured objects for queries, though, you can easily set up a compiler blacklist to prevent you using raw query APIs and be sure that there is no SQL-related data leakage.

Comment: @R.Schmitz Well except that the questions are very rarely about artistic style, and rather about technical differences with more or less well-defined factual pros and cons. So your metaphor isn’t at all apt.

Comment: Programmers used to paint like Jackson Pollack, then Codd / Mondrian came along and tried to make it more clear and peaceful, and people are saying that is wrong, too.

Comment: " You sanitize your input data". **That is the problem**. In particular, "**you**". Having to sanitize data that goes into a database is just as bad as having to sanitize data that goes into your `String` class. It's the 21st century. We don't need to reinvent every wheel. If a database internally is so fragile that it needs sanitizing, it should be behind a standard, field-proven firewall that does the sanitizing.

Comment: @TRiG In my opinion, Martin trolls a bit. I do not know if it's conscious or not. A bit of controversy may be good for public speakers.

Comment: @Jules: Most such ORM's generate SQL under the hood.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: Hyperbole doesn't count as "Uncle Bob's Way,"  for the same reasons that Trump's tweets don't count as US policy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - yes, but if there's no direct connection that allows you to feed text in and have it treated as SQL (or another similar textual form, e.g. Hibernate's HQL), that's just an implementation detail that doesn't really matter.  There's no vulnerability here, unless there is a massive bug in the ORM (and I think that for a well-known library like Hibernate or Rails ActiveRecord such a bug would be unlikely).

Comment: @Jules: Agreed, but that's not Uncle Bob's premise.  If you read the first article that the OP linked, Bob's position (however tongue-in-cheek it might be) is to eliminate SQL from the system entirely.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Did autocorrect mess something up there? *Hyperbole doesn't count as "Uncle Bob's Way" because Twitter is not part of the US government's policy creating process*? My point was that OP asked "*What does Robert C. Martin mean by [...]*" and you literally start with "*Bob Martin's opinion is just that; one man's opinion.*" Phrases like  "random Internet articles" for the guy's very own blog or "one man's hysteria" also give more of an impression of this answer being based on negative feelings, rather than logic.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: To put it another way, you don't answer directly the question "how do I cook eggs Bob Martin's way" if Bob Martin is advocating throwing those eggs against the wall.

Comment: A ***much*** better answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe in RL that's appropriate, but stackexchange is about answering questions *as they are posed*, not about hijacking a thread so you can tell them what you want to tell instead. That is actually the very reason it was created and why it is so much more efficient than forum threads. **The block of text you created is full of argumentation against Mr. Martin, but does not answer any of the 8 questions given here**.

Comment: @R.Schmitz I agree to an extent, but in fact questions like this benefit from answers that provide an alternative viewpoint. Countless times have I read Q/A on this site and learned so much because answerers took different stances than that assumed in the question, or presented an alternative way of thinking about the problem. In the end, as long as it *answers the question* (which this answer does), the community has the voting power to determine what is relevant and useful, and what is not. I found this answer relevant and useful, even if it did not directly state *what Bob Martin means*.

Answer (score 17):

## What is he actually saying?

> Is he saying replace SQL with No-SQL technologies?

## TL;DR: Yes (sort of)

In a more recent talk than the one you linked to on basically the same topic he says: ["The database is a detail. Why do we have databases?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&feature=youtu.be&t=2771).

He claims database came to be to make data access from spinning disks easier, but in the future ["[...] there will not be disks"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&feature=youtu.be&t=3083) thanks to new technology and what he calls "persistent RAM" and that it will be easier to store data using the structures programmers use, such as hashtables or trees.

He goes on to predict that relational databases on a whole will largely disappear due to their new competition:

> [If I were Oracle, I would be pretty scared because the reason for my existence is evaporating from underneath me.[...] The reason for the database to exist is disappearing.](https://youtu.be/o_TH-Y78tt4?t=3157)
>
> [There will probably be some relational tables that survive, but now there is some healthy competition](https://youtu.be/o_TH-Y78tt4?t=3216).

So no, for him it's not only about SQL injection, although he opines [SQL is inherently flawed in this regard](https://youtu.be/o_TH-Y78tt4?t=2819).

---

## Author's note:

The statements in this post are only quotes to understand Robert C. Martin's view on this topic and do not represent the author's opinion. For a more differentiated point of view, see [Robert Harvey's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366573/197693).

Comment: 'Persistent RAM' seemingly only addresses the use of databases for serialising current application state without any regard for forwards or backwards compatibility though. Sure, some databases are used that way but by no means all of them (I realise it's Martin saying this, not you).

Comment: So Martin is actually saying that the only point of databases is abstracting over slow storage? Wow. Then this supports Robert Harvey's answer: His opinion should be taken with a huge grain of salt. For example, this viewpoint fails to consider that the value of a DB is maintaining a consistent and persistent data model. His idea of data structures in “persistent RAM” (SSDs?) is both slow and opens up the possibility of data loss, even NoSQL DBs often use journaling and immutable data structures to safely update persistent records.

Comment: Where is that Holographic Memory from the movie *2001*?

Comment: @amon Yes, Robert Harvey is right offering a more differentiated point of view. But since the OP asked specifically about what Robert C. Martin tries to say I transcribed part of his "newer" talk.

Comment: @amon - see the first sentence of Doc Brown's answer above.  Martin *frequently* makes statements that are massive exaggerations of his point in order to get it across.  He doesn't mean that *all* database operations can be replaced by in-memory stores, any more than he means simply having a component of your application that touches SQL in some form is a massive-enough security risk that it should be avoided in all cases, yet on the face of his words he can be interpreted as saying that.  But all he's really trying to do is make everyone stop and think: is SQL/RDBMS right for my application?

Comment: @Jules I understand that he often exaggerates. But given his reach and reputation, it is quite unhelpful that “Uncle Bob” doesn't make it clear when he's exaggerating and where he's actually saying what he means. If he's supposed to be teaching something, **it's not feasible to double-guess and reinterpret everything he says until it makes any sense**, especially since he doesn't reflect or critique his ideas himself. At some point, it's easier to say “don't listen to him”, or even: *Uncle Bob Considered Harmful*.

Answer (score 11):

SQL is a detail. Knowledge of a detail should not spread.

As SQL is used in more and more places in your code your code becomes more and more dependent on it.

As you learn more and more SQL tricks you solve more and more problems using SQL. This means that switching to another API to persist involves more than just translating. You have to solve problems you didn't realize you had.

You run into this even switching between Databases. One offers fancy whizzbang feature 5 so you use it in a number of places only to find out fancy whizzbang feature 5 is proprietary and now you have a licensing issue that's going to cost a lot of money. So you do a lot of work digging up everywhere you used feature 5 and solving the problem on your own only to find out later you're also using whizzbang feature 3.

One of the things that makes Java so portable is that certain features of the CPU just aren't available. If they were available I'd use them. And suddenly there are CPU's that my Java code won't work on because they don't have those features. It's the same with database features.

It's all to easy to sacrifice your independence without realizing it. SQL is a choice not a given. If you make the decision to use SQL then make it in one place. Make it in a way that can be unmade.

The fact that SQL has security issues and that we're moving to persistent memory models doesn't mean SQL is doomed. It just drives home the point that it's a choice. If you want to preserve the right to make that choice you have to do the work.

---

It may be worth noting that the database movement of the 80's and Uncle Bob have a rather nasty history. He had all his problems solved with a flat file system when management forced a database admin into his life. This event pushed him into his stellar consulting career. (He tells this story in one of his early clean books, forget which) He knows how to solve problems without DB's and has little patience for those that act like using them is a given.

He also tells a story about putting off adding a DB to an application until the last minute when a customer demanded it, and added it in a day as an optional feature. My guess is he see's the way most of us use DB's as an addiction. He's trying to show us how to kick the habit.

Comment: @nocomprende who are you quoting? I don't see that text here.

Comment: Gosh, Einstein, of course.

Comment: Ah, didn't know Einstein knew Bob. Or that Bob was God. Although it sounds like it has the makings of a fun standup bit.

Comment: "Everything that rises must converge"

Comment: @nocomprende you living on a steady diet of motivational posters?

Comment: But Bob *is* God. For some at least.

Comment: I refuse to believe that God is that good at public speaking.

Answer (score 5):

The quote from your first quote is (emphasis mine),

> The solution. The only solution. Is to **eliminate SQL from the system** entirely. If there is no SQL engine, then there can be no SQLi attacks.
>
> What would replace SQL? An API of course! And NOT an API that uses a textual language. Instead, an API that uses an appropriate set of data structures and function calls to access the necessary data.

The rant is against letting application programmers use SQL.

The suggested fix is to let them use an API instead: which isn't SQL and doesn't allow injection.

IMO, examples of such APIs might include:

- http://bobby-tables.com/csharp suggests C# programmers can use the ADO.NET API.

  That's not a perfect example because ADO.NET is a wide or deep (i.e. powerful or general-purpose) API, which *also* allows its users to input raw (or raw-ish) SQL.
- Some SQL developers or database administrators suggest that a database should be configured such that it only permits access via (a limited number of expertly written) [stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459457/what-is-a-stored-procedure), and that application developers shouldn't be allowed to write their own (dangerous) SQL queries
- Another way to "eliminate SQL from the system" is to put the database (which exposes SQL) on some *other* system, accessed via a REST API or similar.

So, IMO, the overall solution or system[s] can still use a database (especially given that a database engine implements useful ACID properties, and scales well and so on, it may be foolish to try to do without one, or to write an application-specific one).

The rant's requirements are satisfied if the database's SQL API is hidden from the application developers, behind some other API (e.g. ADO, perhaps an ORM, a Web service, or whatever).

More generally I suppose it means having an application-specific DAL (a "data access layer" or "database abstraction layer"). A DAL insulates the application from details of how and where the data is stored and/or fetched. The DAL may or may not be implemented using an SQL database.

Comment: I worked on a product that did exactly this 30 years ago. And, the underlying database didn't even support SQL (yet). And, the set of related tables was stored in (wait for it...) a database. The guy who came up with that was really smart. No longer a programmer though.

Comment: I like this answer but I think he might not be saying this. He also states, "Frameworks don’t handle the issue...". From your answer, it seems like you're saying using Linq-to-Sql is okay but isn't that a framework handling the issue?

Comment: @christo8989 I don't know. He mentions Hibernate as an example of a framework that wont handle the issue. And indeed [OWASP says](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hibernate), "Hibernate does not grant immunity to SQL Injection, one can misuse the api as they please. There is nothing special about HQL (Hibernates subset of SQL) that makes it any more or less susceptible." Whereas some of the APIs I mentioned would be better insulators, not exposing SQL at all. Maybe Hibernate is something you might use to implement a DAL (but isn't itself a full-insulating DAL).

Comment: @christo8989 http://augustl.com/blog/2016/datomic_the_most_innovative_db_youve_never_heard_of/ suggests that Datomic is (just) another wrapper/layer around a (possibly-SQL) database -- "Datomic does not write directly to the file system. Instead, you can use a number of different databases as a storage backend for Datomic: Any SQL JDBC database, etc."

Comment: It should be noted that the [solution for avoiding SQL injection in ADO.NET](http://www.bobby-tables.com/adodotnet) is not all that complicated -- use placeholders in the SQL, use parameters in the command, and set the value of said parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone seems to be answering this question from a security standpoint, or with an SQL lens.

I saw a Robert Martin lecture where he recounts that as programmers, we use many different data structures that are optimal for our specific programs. So, rather than universally storing all data in a tabular structure, we should store our data in hash tables, trees, etc so we can grab the data and jump right in to the program.

I interpreted his message as only saying we should throw out our current assumptions about persistent storage for a moment to consider other future possibilities than the age-old SQL tabular format. SSD is a candidate solution, but not the only one.

Comment: What might he think about multi-user concurrent read/write of the data?

Comment: @ChrisW I don't think this is an issue of implementation, rather a high-level idea of finding a way to do persistent data storage better.

Comment: @ChrisW He also talks about transactional databases. Putting source control technology as your persistence tool. In that, you only create and read which is much more concurrent friendly than transactions and updates.

Comment: @Keenan So he's not really offering a solution via implementation. He's just saying, think about what could be?

Comment: @christo8989 Whether he has personally spearheaded devolopment of candidate solutions for the persistent storage problem in computer science, I don't know. That is outside the scope of the OP's question. 

Uncle Bob is all about plug-in architecture. The current industry standard of applications development is tightly coupling to a database and building the application around it, the app depends on the db, when the db should depend on the app.

Rather, Uncle Bob proposes that 'the database is a detail' and should be decoupled and replaceable.

Answer (score 2):

I want to address only a short statement:

> Or does he just want people to stop using SQL/Relational Databases
>   because of SQLi attacks?

No. That is a wrong assumption. We can not say we must stop using cars, because they are responsible of people dying in car accidents. In the same way, SQL/relational databases (or anything else in this context, such as RDBMS) are not responsible for malicious SQL payload an attacker can perform on your web application. I am sure the author did not mean that, because there is a whole [SQL injection prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for this purpose.

Comment: Automated cars would prevent about 98% of car accidents. We need to trust the machine *more*, heh heh heh.

Comment: “We can not say we must stop using cars [except out of special and/or carefully controlled circumstances] because they are responsible of people dying in car accidents.” — Uhm. We can *absolutely* say that. And many reasonable people do.

Comment: You are basically saying: *An application developed in Java is hacked so we must stop using Java*.  Downvoting is enough and for the rest, I am not here to teach you common sense. @KonradRudolph

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ That’s a somewhat false equivalence (since nothing is safe from hacking) but it’s not entirely far off either: there are languages that, on balance, shouldn’t be used because there are better alternatives; for instance, if you’re using C outside of the context of system programming you’re doing it wrong. Anyway, I didn’t downvote your answer but it *is* wrong: because contrary to what you claim, that is exactly what Bob Martin is saying (as other answers show).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, he is not to use databases and SQL - fairly explicitly.  The first reference is a well know issue, the second reference comes off sounding like a rant. Although, I am interpreting it as to have a good reason to use databases and not to use SQL.  From my perspective this is not even reasonable advise.

Unfortunately, the example he is using is a well know example with a well known solution that he then points out.  It usually comes about when a programmer doesn't realize what he is doing.  For example constructing strings containing SQL like:

```
    my $sql="select a from b where a=$ui_val;";
    prepare($sql)
    execute($sql)
```

as opposed to

```
    my $sql="select a from b where a=?;";
    prepare($sql)
    execute($sql,$ui_val);
```

This is a DBI perl like example for the ruby on rails code.  The rails code that he provides is easy to confuse between the safe and the unsafe.  Like many ORMs hides what the SQL is underneath and so often you are dealing with an interface that constructs and executes the sql for you.  Doesn't this sound almost like what an API would be doing for you?

My interpretation of the first reference is that he is suggesting that we should replace a well known issue that has a well known solution.

It is also unfortunate that he doesn't mention that if this is done correctly it will make code easier to write and more readable, though if it is done well, it may actually be harder to write and less readable.  Additionally, he doesn't mention is that SQL is really very easy to read and does what you would generally expect it to do.

He is partially correct, ultimately we will have an infinitely large and fast memory and an infinitely fast processor.  Until we slip out from the current physics that constrains computing, he is not correct.

Yes spinning disk are a thing of the past, and we now use SSDs.  Disks work with about ~10 milliseconds per data transfer, SSDs work with ~0.5 milliseconds (500 microsec) data access time.  RAM is on the order of 100 nano seconds, processors operate on the oder of 100s of pico seconds.  This is the heart of why we need databases.  Databases manage the data transfer between either spinning disks or SSDs with main memory.  The advent of SSDs haven't eliminated the need for databases.

Comment: *"STOP USING SQL"* (cited from the first link) sounds very much like he is saying not to use SQL, to my understanding.

Comment: It is a word order issue. Actually this was originally a telegram: USING SQL STOP

Comment: @nocomprende So you’re saying that he’s the victim of a race condition? Well, oops. He could have avoided that by using SQL transactions.

Comment: Maybe it is a very short mixture of Visual Basic and Fortran. Where will it all END?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Well, that is where R. Martin has a point. Transactions are moving to the CPU. Xeon has TSX, and soon can use TSX on Optane storage and RAM alike.

Comment: @MSalters Aren’t we on a completely different layer here though? Hardware TM is all nice and well but does it work with complex memory access patterns? How easy is controlling it in high-level languages (caveat: I know virtually nothing about hardware TM, these are genuine questions)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Well, I think we would agree that virtually noone is going to be using TSX straight from assembly. There will be higher-level abstractions. Will those abstract transactions be SQL transactions? I think not. As an interpreted language, SQL carries a performance overhead. That really didn't matter when you accessed data on rotating harddisks. It is unaffordable however when accessing data in RAM.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

> does he just want people to stop using SQL/Relational Databases because of SQLi attacks?

The 'Bobby Tables' article seems to suggest that this, it and of itself is a reason to not use SQL:

> The solution. The only solution. Is to eliminate SQL from the system entirely. If there is no SQL engine, then there can be no SQLi attacks.

He might have other reasons that he discusses elsewhere. I wouldn't know because I don't really read much of his stuff.

## Digression

This part isn't really an answer, but I think the question of the value of SQL is far more interesting (as do others, apparently.)

I've had a lot of experience using SQL and I think I have a fair understanding of its strengths and weaknesses.  My personal feeling is that it's been overused and abused, but that the idea that we should never use it is kind of silly.  The idea that we must choose 'SQL always' or 'SQL never' is a false dichotomy.

As far as SQL injection being an argument for not using SQL, that's laughable.  This is a well understood problem with a pretty simple solution.  The problem with this argument is that SQLi isn't the only vulnerability that exists.  If you think that using JSON APIs makes you safe, you are in for a big surprise.

I think every developer should [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqHsaVhlxAQ&list=PLpr-xdpM8wG9g8l21uzfgyx4xAJ9aY7e7&index=1) titled "Friday the 13th: Attacking JSON - Alvaro Muñoz & Oleksandr Mirosh - AppSecUSA 2017"

If you don't have the time or inclination to watch through it, here's the gist: A lot of JSON deserialization libraries have remote code execution vulnerabilities.  If you are using XML, you have even more to worry about.  Banning SQL from your architecture will not make your system secure.

Comment: Nobody claimed that banning SQL would, by itself, make your system secure. Uncle Bob claims that it makes your system **more** secure, and given that SQL injection remains the biggest risk in web application security for over a decade now, I think you should not lightly dismiss the need for the industry to improve the way it talks to databases.

Comment: @meriton Sorry, but "solution, the only solution" seems pretty clear.  The solution to the problem of SQLi is known and quite simple.  People who can't be bothered use prepare statements are going to create insecure systems regardless of whether they stop using SQL.  These are unprofessional people who need to start following basic good practices or get a new job.

Answer (score 2):

Martin's problem appears to be with programmers building dynamic SQL *directly* from user input, something like (forgive me, I'm primarily a C and C++ programmer):

```
sprintf( query, "select foo from bar where %s;", user_input );
```

which is *absolutely* a recipe for heartburn (hence the [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) strip).  Any programmer that puts code like that in a production system deserves a paddlin'.

You can mitigate (if not entirely eliminate) the problem by using prepared statements and properly sanitizing your inputs.  If you can hide the SQL behind an API such that programmers aren't directly building query strings, so much the better (which is part of what Martin advocates).

But as to getting rid of SQL entirely, I don't think that's practical or desirable.  Relational models are *useful*, that's why they exist in the first place, and SQL is probably the best interface for working with relational models.

As always, it's a matter of using the right tool for the job.  If your shopping cart app doesn't need a full-up relational model, then *don't use a relational model* (meaning you won't need to use SQL).  For the times you do need a relational model, then you're almost certainly going to be working with SQL.

Comment: While `sprintf` doesn't contain the kind of sanitization that SQL requires, the functions that are designed specifically for this purpose *do,* and are perfectly safe.  Example: [SqlQuery in Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%28System.Type,System.String,System.Object[]%29).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I would assume that's the case.  For my part, I mostly do server-side work in C and C++, so I still see occasionally see (thankfully rare) examples of people just `sprintf`-ing dynamic SQL, which is Not How You Do It.

Answer (score 1):

The two sources you link convey different messages:

The blog post says that data access logic should not exist as text at runtime, lest it be mixed with untrusted user input. That is, the blog post condemns writing queries by concatenating strings.

The lecture is different. The first difference is in tone: The lecture speculates and calls into question, but does not condemn. He doesn't say that databases are evil, but challenges us to imagine persistence without a database. He argues that in the 30 years since relational databases became widespread many things have changed, and highlights two which might conceivably affect our choice of persistence technology:

- storage space has increased by a factor of about 1 million - at comparable prices! Consequently, it is less necessary to conserve storage, and in particular, it is no longer necessary to delete. By using append-only storage, concurrency control can be simplified because read locks are unnecessary. This can obviate the need for transactions.
- access times have fallen, because most datasets now fit in RAM, massively reducing read latency.

Do these changed circumstances change the optimal persistence technology? Interestingly, Uncle Bob doesn't say - presumably because he feels no answer would be correct for all programs. That's why he cautions us to treat our choice of persistence technology as a detail rather than enshrine it into stone tablets and pass it on as received wisdom to our peers.

**Do alternatives exist?**

Writing data access logic without strings is entirely possible. In Java land, you might use [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/), where queries are described using a type-safe fluent API generated from your database schema. Such a query might look as follows:

```
JPAQuery<?> query = new JPAQuery<Void>(entityManager);
Customer bob = query.select(customer)
  .from(customer)
  .where(customer.firstName.eq("Bob"))
  .fetchOne();
```

As you can see, the query logic is not expressed as a String, clearly separating the trusted structure of the query from the untrusted parameters (and of course, QueryDSL never includes the parameters into the query text, but uses prepared statements to separate the query for its parameters at the JDBC level). To achieve SQL injection with QueryDSL, you'd have to write your own parser to parse a string and translate it into a syntax tree, and even if you did that, you probably wouldn't add support for nasty things like `select ... into file`. In short, QueryDSL makes SQL injection neigh impossible, and also improves programmer productivity and increases refactoring safety. Prevented the biggest risk to web application security, that has existed long enough to spawn [running gags](https://xkcd.com/327/), and boosted developer productivity? I dare say that if you still write queries as strings, you're doing it wrong.

As for alternatives to relational data bases, it is curious to know that postgres' [multi version concurrency control](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-mvcc-multi-version-concurrency-control-work/) is exactly that kind of append-only data structure Uncle Bob is talking about, though he was probably thinking more of [event stores](https://eventstore.org/), and the [event sourcing pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/event-sourcing) in general, which also fits nicely with the notion of keeping current state in RAM.